# Retrieving Facebook post comments + replies with their likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve comments on facebook posts with the number of likes they got.

I did find a useful script here (step 6): https://nocodewebscraping.com/how-to-extract-data-from-facebook-page-competitor-analysis/#comments

```
https://graph.facebook.com/204153042939851_761338343887982/comments?limit=900&access_token=EACEdE (Truncated)
```

The problem is that I don't manage to get the replies. 
I thought I could try directly in the Graph Api Explorer and add &filer=stream but then I lose the like_count for each comment.

Any ideas of what I should modify in the URL in order to have the comments+replies and the like count?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fieldexpansion) to make nested queries.

For example, the following will get you the comments on the post, and for each comment will get the message, like_count, replies. For each reply you'll also get the message and like_count:

`204153042939851_761338343887982?fields=comments{message,like_count,comments{message,like_count}}`

Comment: Thank you! But then the names and user id are missing. Is it possible to add nested queries for these too? I did try something but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can access the author of the comment in the `from` field, so:

`204153042939851_761338343887982?fields=comments{from{id,name},message,like_count,comments{message,like_count,from{id,name}}}`

Comment: This is what I get:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"?\".\" at character 38: from{id,name\u200c\u200b},message,like_count\u200c\u200b,comments{message,li\u200c\u200bke_count,from{id,nam\u200c\u200be}}",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "CIrM2lRM9+D"
   }
}